# Mix (or sort) JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the only array:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

The "first half" of array's data is [0,1,2,3,4] and the second is [5,6,7,8].

Now I should get something like this (it is not random mixing)

```
[0, 5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4]
```

This is an array of data for two columns. I should place first half of data in first column, and the second one in second column.

I'm trying to find a simple solution... Thanks for advice!

Comment: what is ***half*** in this case?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry for my English) In my first example the array.length = 9, and the "half" is Math.ceil(array.length/2) => 5 ...

Comment: What have you tried so far [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `split` your array in half using `Math.ceil` to round up number and then loop first part and add each element from second part incrementing counter by 2.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], c = 1

var half = arr.splice(Math.ceil(arr.length / 2))
half.forEach(e => (arr.splice(c, 0, e), c += 2))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, using map and an inline if statement

```js
    var array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    var result = array.map(function(item,index){
      return (index%2 == 0) ? array[index/2] :  array[Math.floor((index+array.length)/2)];
    });
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: You probably want `index>>1` not `index/2` here. Your note is valid for python2, for example, but JS will give you a float.

Comment: I added a code snippet, index/2 gives floor(index/2), it is a number not a float

Comment: @AloïsdeLaComble And now Increase an array length by 1... result went wrong

Comment: You are right ! My mistake ! It works with Math.floor

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the index and map the value from the array.

> ```
> (i >> 1) + ((i & 1) * ((a.length + 1) >> 1))
> ^^^^^^^^                                     take the half integer value
>             ^^^^^^                           check for odd
>                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^       adjust length
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  the half value of adjusted length
> ```

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    result = array.map((_, i, a) => a[(i >> 1) + ((i & 1) * ((a.length + 1) >> 1))]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```